# JQuery: Toggle question

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

How do you fire a JQuery toggled event once, and only once, another JQuery toggled event has been completed?

I have the following:

- I have `<div id="displayDivWhenPageLoads">...</div>` - this DIV is show (visible) when the web page loads.
- I also have `<div id="displayDivWhenToggledSelected">...</div>` - this DIV is hidden (`display:none`) when the web page first loads.

What I want to do is when someone presses my JQuery toggle action button, it

1. toggles the div=displayDivWhenPageLoads so that the div is no longer displayed (display:none)
2. Then once, and only once, the displayDivWhenPageLoads DIV has been toggled so that it's no longer visible, then toggled the div=displayDivWhenToggledSelected so that this div now becomes toggled visibile.

Make sense?

I've been looking at the API http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle#speedcallback and it's just not clear to me on how to fire off a second toggled once the first toggled has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

I think I follow what you're asking for. You need to use callback functions. Try this:

```
$('#actionButton').click(function() {
  $('#displayDivWhenPageLoads').slideUp('slow', function() {
    $('#displayDivWhenToggledSelected').slideDown('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#actionButton").click(function(){  
  $("#displayDivWhenPageLoads"). slideToggle({
    speed:"slow",
    callback : "ToggleOther"
  })
  return false;
 })

function ToggleOther()
{
  $("#displayDivWhenToggledSelected "). slideToggle("slow");
}
```